# form does not get through POST

Tags: php

```
$product = '';
                            
                            $stmt = $verbinding->query("SELECT 
                            product_category, product_id, parent FROM 
                            Productcategory ORDER BY product_category");

                            $categorien = $stmt->fetchAll();
                           
                                foreach($categorien as $cats){
                                  if($cats['parent'] === $producten){
                                   
                                    echo '<form action="product-list.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" name="cats" value="'. $cats['product_category'] .'"></form>';
                                    echo $producten;
                                    
                                    //var_dump($_POST);
                                    
                                    if(isset($_POST['cats'])){
                                        echo $_POST['cats'];
                                        echo $cats['product_category'];
                                        echo $cats['product_id'];

                                    if($_POST['cats'] === $cats['product_category']){
                                        $product = $cats['product_id'];
                                        echo $product;
                                        echo "gelukt!!";
                                    }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

So to update my question this is code that does partly work but does not get past the if($_POST['cats'] === $cats['product_id']){ statement. The problem is that my $_POST['cats'] just sends NO information. I can't understand why though. I should say though that I use the same "name" value in another form, but if I don't it wont even go through the if(isset($_POST['cats'])){ statement.

Comment: What _is_ in`$_POST` when you display it for debugging?

Comment: `form action="product-list.php"` is product-list.php the same page?

Comment: If these are numerical values `$_POST['categorien'] === $cat['product_category']` then you should use a simple comparison `== ` or typecasting them.

Answer (score 0):

From your form the action page is "product-list.php", is it the same page you are handling the form logic in?

If not then your you need to write the code below in the product-list.php you created.

```
    ....
      if(isset($_POST['categorien'])){
            echo "pastcategory?";
            if($_POST['categorien'] === $cat['product_category']){
                $producten = $cat['product_id'];
                echo "pastcategory!!!!";
                echo $producten;
            }
        }
     ....
```

Comment: Yes, my code is indeed written in the product-list.php.

Comment: Your are conditionally rendering the form and the logic handling the form `if($cat['parent'] === $producten)` maybe the condition was not met

Comment: It does meet, since the code in the if statement does execute.